# Exclude the Wordpress Admin Role From Being Impacted By This PHP Code

Tags: php, wordpress

I have code that I'm using to place limits on form submissions in WordPress to avoid spam. If one of the limitations is triggered, the form doesn't display and instead there's a message. I'm trying to modify the code so that it shows the form in its default state if an admin is logged in.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Gravity Forms Limit Submit
* Plugin URI: https://www.sagelaundry.com.com/
* Description: Limit submissions from Gravity Forms.
* Version: 0.1
* Author: Lloyd Silver
* Author URI: https://www.sagelaundry.com.com/
**/


class GW_Submission_Limit {

    var $_args;
    var $_notification_event;

    private static $forms_with_individual_settings = array();

    public function __construct( $args ) {

        // make sure we're running the required minimum version of Gravity Forms
        if ( ! property_exists( 'GFCommon', 'version' ) || ! version_compare( GFCommon::$version, '1.8', '>=' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->_args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
            'form_id'              => false,
            'form_ids'             => array(),
            'limit'                => 1,
            'limit_by'             => 'ip', // 'ip', 'user_id', 'role', 'embed_url', 'field_value'
            'time_period'          => 60 * 60 * 24, // integer in seconds or 'day', 'month', 'year' to limit to current day, month, or year respectively
            'limit_message'        => __( 'Sorry, you have reached the submission limit for this form.' ),
            'apply_limit_per_form' => true,
            'enable_notifications' => false,
        ) );

        if ( ! is_array( $this->_args['limit_by'] ) ) {
            $this->_args['limit_by'] = array( $this->_args['limit_by'] );
        }

        if ( empty( $this->_args['form_ids'] ) ) {
            if ( $this->_args['form_id'] === false ) {
                $this->_args['form_ids'] = false;
            } elseif ( ! is_array( $this->_args['form_id'] ) ) {
                $this->_args['form_ids'] = array( $this->_args['form_id'] );
            } else {
                $this->_args['form_ids'] = $this->_args['form_id'];
            }
        }

        if ( $this->_args['form_ids'] ) {
            foreach ( $this->_args['form_ids'] as $form_id ) {
                self::$forms_with_individual_settings[] = $form_id;
            }
        }

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );

    }

    public function init() {

        add_filter( 'gform_pre_render', array( $this, 'pre_render' ) );
        add_filter( 'gform_validation', array( $this, 'validate' ) );

        if ( $this->_args['enable_notifications'] ) {

            $this->enable_notifications();

            add_action( 'gform_after_submission', array( $this, 'maybe_send_limit_reached_notifications' ), 10, 2 );

        }

    }

    public function pre_render( $form ) {

        if ( ! $this->is_applicable_form( $form ) || ! $this->is_limit_reached( $form['id'] ) ) {
            return $form;
        }

        $submission_info = rgar( GFFormDisplay::$submission, $form['id'] );

        // if no submission, hide form
        // if submission and not valid, hide form
        // unless 'field_value' limiter is applied
        if ( ( ! $submission_info || ! rgar( $submission_info, 'is_valid' ) ) && ! $this->is_limited_by_field_value() ) {
            add_filter( 'gform_get_form_filter_' . $form['id'], array( $this, 'get_limit_message' ), 10, 2 );
        }

        return $form;

    }

    public function get_limit_message() {
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <div class="limit-message">
            <?php echo do_shortcode( $this->_args['limit_message'] ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public function validate( $validation_result ) {

        if ( ! $this->is_applicable_form( $validation_result['form'] ) || ! $this->is_limit_reached( $validation_result['form']['id'] ) ) {
            return $validation_result;
        }

        $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;

        if ( $this->is_limited_by_field_value() ) {
            $field_ids = array_map( 'intval', $this->get_limit_field_ids() );
            foreach ( $validation_result['form']['fields'] as &$field ) {
                if ( in_array( $field['id'], $field_ids ) ) {
                    $field['failed_validation']  = true;
                    $field['validation_message'] = do_shortcode( $this->_args['limit_message'] );
                }
            }
        }

        return $validation_result;
    }

    public function is_limit_reached( $form_id ) {
        return $this->get_entry_count( $form_id ) >= $this->get_limit();
    }

    public function get_entry_count( $form_id ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $where = array();
        $join  = array();

        $where[] = 'e.status = "active"';

        foreach ( $this->_args['limit_by'] as $limiter ) {
            switch ( $limiter ) {
                case 'role': // user ID is required when limiting by role
                case 'user_id':
                    $where[] = $wpdb->prepare( 'e.created_by = %s', get_current_user_id() );
                    break;
                case 'embed_url':
                    $where[] = $wpdb->prepare( 'e.source_url = %s', GFFormsModel::get_current_page_url() );
                    break;
                case 'field_value':
                    $values = $this->get_limit_field_values( $form_id, $this->get_limit_field_ids() );

                    // if there is no value submitted for any of our fields, limit is never reached
                    if ( empty( $values ) ) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    foreach ( $values as $field_id => $value ) {
                        $table_slug = sprintf( 'em%s', str_replace( '.', '_', $field_id ) );
                        $join[]     = "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}gf_entry_meta {$table_slug} ON {$table_slug}.entry_id = e.id";
                        // phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.PreparedSQL.InterpolatedNotPrepared
                        $where[] = $wpdb->prepare( "\n( ( {$table_slug}.meta_key BETWEEN %s AND %s ) AND {$table_slug}.meta_value = %s )", doubleval( $field_id ) - 0.001, doubleval( $field_id ) + 0.001, $value );
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    $where[] = $wpdb->prepare( 'ip = %s', GFFormsModel::get_ip() );
            }
        }

        if ( $this->_args['apply_limit_per_form'] || ( ! $this->is_global( $form_id ) && count( $this->_args['form_ids'] ) <= 1 ) ) {
            $where[] = $wpdb->prepare( 'e.form_id = %d', $form_id );
        } else {
            $where[] = $wpdb->prepare( 'e.form_id IN( %s )', implode( ', ', $this->_args['form_ids'] ) );
        }

        $time_period     = $this->_args['time_period'];
        $time_period_sql = false;

        if ( $time_period === false ) {
            // no time period
        } elseif ( intval( $time_period ) > 0 ) {
            $time_period_sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'date_created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(utc_timestamp(), INTERVAL %d SECOND) AND utc_timestamp()', $this->_args['time_period'] );
        } else {

            $gmt_offset  = get_option( 'gmt_offset' );
            $date_func   = $gmt_offset < 0 ? 'DATE_SUB' : 'DATE_ADD';
            $hour_offset = abs( $gmt_offset );

            $date_created_sql  = sprintf( '%s( date_created, INTERVAL %d HOUR )', $date_func, $hour_offset );
            $utc_timestamp_sql = sprintf( '%s( utc_timestamp(), INTERVAL %d HOUR )', $date_func, $hour_offset );

            switch ( $time_period ) {
                case 'per_day':
                case 'day':
                    $time_period_sql = "DATE( $date_created_sql ) = DATE( $utc_timestamp_sql )";
                    break;
                case 'per_week':
                case 'week':
                    $time_period_sql  = "WEEK( $date_created_sql ) = WEEK( $utc_timestamp_sql )";
                    $time_period_sql .= "AND YEAR( $date_created_sql ) = YEAR( $utc_timestamp_sql )";
                    break;
                case 'per_month':
                case 'month':
                    $time_period_sql  = "MONTH( $date_created_sql ) = MONTH( $utc_timestamp_sql )";
                    $time_period_sql .= "AND YEAR( $date_created_sql ) = YEAR( $utc_timestamp_sql )";
                    break;
                case 'per_year':
                case 'year':
                    $time_period_sql = "YEAR( $date_created_sql ) = YEAR( $utc_timestamp_sql )";
                    break;
            }
        }

        if ( $time_period_sql ) {
            $where[] = $time_period_sql;
        }

        $where = implode( ' AND ', $where );
        $join  = implode( "\n", $join );

        $sql = "SELECT count( e.id )
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}gf_entry e
                $join
                WHERE $where";

        // phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.PreparedSQL.NotPrepared
        $entry_count = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

        return $entry_count;
    }

    public function is_limited_by_field_value() {
        return in_array( 'field_value', $this->_args['limit_by'] );
    }

    public function get_limit_field_ids() {

        $limit = $this->_args['limit'];

        if ( is_array( $limit ) ) {
            $field_ids = array_keys( $this->_args['limit'] );
            $field_ids = array( array_shift( $field_ids ) );
        } else {
            $field_ids = $this->_args['fields'];
        }

        return $field_ids;
    }

    public function get_limit_field_values( $form_id, $field_ids ) {

        $form   = GFAPI::get_form( $form_id );
        $values = array();

        foreach ( $field_ids as $field_id ) {

            $field = GFFormsModel::get_field( $form, $field_id );
            if ( ! $field ) {
                continue;
            }

            $input_name = 'input_' . str_replace( '.', '_', $field_id );
            $value      = GFFormsModel::prepare_value( $form, $field, rgpost( $input_name ), $input_name, null );

            if ( ! rgblank( $value ) ) {
                $values[ "$field_id" ] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $values;
    }

    public function get_limit() {

        $limit = $this->_args['limit'];

        if ( $this->is_limited_by_field_value() ) {
            $limit = is_array( $limit ) ? array_shift( $limit ) : intval( $limit );
        } elseif ( in_array( 'role', $this->_args['limit_by'] ) ) {
            $limit = rgar( $limit, $this->get_user_role() );
        }

        return intval( $limit );
    }

    public function get_user_role() {

        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $role = reset( $user->roles );

        return $role;
    }

    public function enable_notifications() {

        if ( ! class_exists( 'GW_Notification_Event' ) ) {

            _doing_it_wrong( 'GW_Inventory::$enable_notifications', __( 'Inventory notifications require the \'GW_Notification_Event\' class.' ), '1.0' );

        } else {

            $event_slug = implode( array_filter( array( 'gw_submission_limit_limit_reached', $this->_args['form_id'] ) ) );
            $event_name = GFForms::get_page() == 'notification_edit' ? __( 'Submission limit reached' ) : __( 'Event name is only populated on Notification Edit view; saves a DB call to get the form on every ' );

            $this->_notification_event = new GW_Notification_Event( array(
                'form_id'    => $this->_args['form_id'],
                'event_name' => $event_name,
                'event_slug' => $event_slug,
                //'trigger'    => array( $this, 'notification_event_listener' )
            ) );

        }

    }

    public function maybe_send_limit_reached_notifications( $entry, $form ) {

        if ( $this->is_applicable_form( $form ) && $this->is_limit_reached( $form['id'] ) ) {
            $this->send_limit_reached_notifications( $form, $entry );
        }

    }

    public function send_limit_reached_notifications( $form, $entry ) {

        $this->_notification_event->send_notifications( $this->_notification_event->get_event_slug(), $form, $entry, true );

    }

    public function is_applicable_form( $form ) {

        $form_id          = isset( $form['id'] ) ? $form['id'] : $form;
        $is_specific_form = ! $this->is_global( $form_id ) ? in_array( $form_id, $this->_args['form_ids'] ) : false;

        return $this->is_global( $form_id ) || $is_specific_form;
    }

    public function is_global( $form ) {
        $form_id = isset( $form['id'] ) ? $form['id'] : $form;
        return empty( $this->_args['form_ids'] ) && ! in_array( $form_id, self::$forms_with_individual_settings );
    }
}
class GWSubmissionLimit extends GW_Submission_Limit { }

new GW_Submission_Limit( array(
    'form_id'       => 22,
    'limit_by'      => 'ip',
    'limit'         => 1,
    'time_period'   => false,
    'limit_message' => '',
) );
?>
```

I tried getting the user role and storing it in a variable and then adding it to this line as an additional OR (||) statement but it keeps resulting in a critical error.

```
if ( ! $this->is_applicable_form( $form ) || ! $this->is_limit_reached( $form['id'] ) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, You can check if the currently logged-in user is an admin by

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    // Code
}
```

**current_user_can** checks the capabilities of the user. It returns a boolean value.
**manage_options** is one of the admin capabilities.